# Como inserir cabeçalho e rodapé em documeto docx utilizando Apache Poi

Tags: java, microsoft-word, apache-poi

Estou tentando inserir cabecalho e rodapé num arquivo gerado automaticamente docx, a imagem carrega porém ela não fica visível no arquivo.

Segue o meu código:

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

CTSectPr sectPr = doc.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(doc,sectPr);
CTP ctpHeader = CTP.Factory.newInstance();

XWPFParagraph headerParagraph = new XWPFParagraph(ctpHeader, doc);

XWPFRun headerRun= headerParagraph.createRun();
String imgFile="ImagemCabecalho3.png";
headerRun.addPicture(new FileInputStream(imgFile),XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, imgFile, Units.toEMU(450), Units.toEMU(60));

headerParagraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

XWPFParagraph[] parsHeader = new XWPFParagraph[1];
parsHeader[0] = headerParagraph;
policy.createHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT, parsHeader);
```

[image: Como aparece no arquivo]

Answer (score 0):

Consegui carregar as imagens do cabeçalho e rodapé.
Segue o código abaixo:

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

CTSectPr sectPr = doc.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(doc,sectPr);

//Criando Header
XWPFHeader header = policy.createHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT);

XWPFParagraph paragraph = header.getParagraphArray(0);
if (paragraph == null) paragraph = header.createParagraph();

paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

XWPFRun headerRun= paragraph.createRun();
String imgFileHeader ="ImagemCabecalho3.png";
headerRun.addPicture(new FileInputStream(imgFileHeader), XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, imgFileHeader, Units.toEMU(520), Units.toEMU(60));
headerRun.addBreak();

//Criando Footer
XWPFFooter footer = policy.createFooter(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT);
paragraph = footer.getParagraphArray(0);
if (paragraph == null) paragraph = footer.createParagraph();

paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

XWPFRun footerRun= paragraph.createRun();
String imgFileFooter ="ImagemRodape3.png";
footerRun.addPicture(new FileInputStream(imgFileFooter), XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, imgFileFooter, Units.toEMU(520), Units.toEMU(60));
```